# What was ICommand originally designed for?

Tags: wpf, xaml

We all know that MVVM proponents love the ICommand, but what was it originally designed for?

Answer (score 0):

The [command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is a generic design pattern, it serves to *encapsulate a request*, which allows one to pass it around for example, which here is handy for data binding. But the encapsulation itself is rather useful for looser coupling.

Comment: I'm looking for something more specific than vague notions of "loose coupling". And perferably actual documentation from the .NET 3.0 era.

Comment: @JonathanAllen: Why would they need a specific reason to implement an ancient pattern that ostensibly is useful in certain scenarios (like e.g. transactions)?

Comment: @JonathanAllen Only the members of the .NET team that designed and implemented ICommand can possibly give a categorical answer to your question. Anything else will be conjecture. Hence H.B.'s answer, and my vote to migrate this to http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ICommand is not an ancient pattern. It is part of a bigger plan dealing that includes data binding, the CommandBinding class, and the RoutedUICommand class. Whlie the way we use it has changed dramatically, there was a specific use intended for this interface.

Comment: @djacobson And there is probably some documentation on the subject that they wrote. It is just a matter of finding it.

Comment: @JonathanAllen: Those are all assumptions on your part, also i did not say that `ICommand` is an ancient pattern, it's an implementation of the ancient pattern called **Command**, which can be found in "Design Patterns" by the Gang of Four...

Comment: The ICommand interface cannot be used to implement the GoF Command pattern because it doesn't "encapsulate all the information needed to call a method at a later time".

Comment: @JonathanAllen: It's not a strict implementation, there usually is no `Action` method being called by the command, so it does not need that information, but it could be adapted to do so and storing information surely is not a problem when implementing the interface.

Answer (score 0):

ICommand is in PresentationCore, which I believe indicates that it was originally designed for WPF and MVVM.  That's the assembly for core WPF components.